# Insert to data table where values are equal to mine variables

Tags: c#, mysql

```
 private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
        string s1 = "";
        s1 = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string s2 = "";
        s2 = comboBox2.Items[comboBox2.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string s3 = "";
        s3 = comboBox3.Items[comboBox3.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=D:\Desktop\DB2\DB2\Database1.sdf");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Kambariai values ('" + textBox1.Text + "') where Kliento ID='" + s + "',Kambario rūšis='" + s1 + "',Vietų skaičius='" + s2 + "',Viešnagės laikas dienomis='" + s3 + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Duomenys įrašyti";
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

So here is the deal,  I trying to put textbox value to datatable where s1,s2,s3 values are equal to combobox values. Tell me what I am doing wrong, I am getting error 
error-> There was error parsing the query . [ Token line number = 1, toke line offset = 40, token in error where.

Comment: Look up the `insert` syntax. Do you actually want to update an existing record? Then use `update` instead.

Comment: All your columns are character type? [`INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) doesn't have a syntax with `WHERE` statement as far as I know. And always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this where you need to make adjustment to your code

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("update Kambariai set your_field_name='" + textBox1.Text + "' where Kliento ID='" + s + "'and Kambario rūšis='" + s1 + "'and Vietų skaičius='" + s2 + "'and Viešnagės laikas dienomis='" + s3 + "'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```